# When I'm Clicking the VR Button in a-frame, I'm not able to view it

Tags: aframe

When in VR mode the view got freezes and it stuck in first frame itself(Android/iOS).

Link: https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/
Press VR button available in bottom right in any android or iOS device.

Comment: Hi Abul, please try to be more specific. What did you do, what is the background. We can only help you with your problem, if we know what you already did.

Comment: Hey Micheal. I found the solution. I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is Chrome WebVR is currently in beta. So we need to enable it by

> chrome://flags/

then search WebVR and enable it.